# google cloud platform billing account china

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, billing

**I can't create billing account for China.**
I just want to use the Google Map Platform, before this is free and easy to use.
I am happy to pay for Google Map Platform, but I'm Chinese. I don't have any visa or JCB credit card.

This is a confusing question.

Maybe the Google Map Platform can support paypal to create billing account?
By the way, Google map is well. I like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that according to our Maps Platform Terms of Service, section [3.2.4 (f)](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license), usage in prohibited territories is not allowed, and China is on the [list of Prohibited Territories](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories/).

It is not permissible to set up Maps APIs using projects associated with a billing account from a prohibited territory, or include Maps APIs with a [Customer Application](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#21definitions)  built for use within a prohibited territory. For further questions regarding the Maps Platform Terms of Service, please work with your legal representative for guidance.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Comment: Thank you for supporting and liking Google Maps :)